# Docusign Email authentication

Tags: email, authentication, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign for sending email to client/end user by using createEnvelope API of DocuSign. if the end user forwards the email to someone else he /she can view the document and sign on his/her behalf.
so I have used `signer.accessCode = "random value"` and passing this value again to end-user/client so that while viewing document he/she needs to place the code which I sent in a different email and its working properly till now.
The problem arises when the recipient views the document and did not sign it and accidentally forward the email to someone else..now that person can view document easily without entering the access code as DocuSign does not ask to place an accessCode second time or once the document is viewed. Is there any config setting or any property in code which I can apply for this case?
I want DocuSign to ask the accessCode popup every time when the end user wants to view it.

Secondly, is there any provision to automatically delete a document from DocuSign if the end user did not sign the document for any specific number of days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options under **Go to Admin > Security Settings** that can mitigate this concern. The primary option you want is **Recipient Authentication Triggers: Every Time a recipient accesses an envelope**. You may also want **Login Requirements: Login Required if Signer has an Account**.

For the second question, you'll want to set an Envelope Expiration. When an envelope has expired, recipients who have not signed are unable to access it.

Comment: ThanksJasurbek. this was helpful one more point i wanted to ask now i am able to pass the access code through email to recipient/client to view document. is there any provision to set an expiry period for access code and how to regenerate it again? as of now we are generating the access code as per specific request. so the access code is generated only when the request is initiated.